# DynamoDB "Serialized object is not a valid json Object"

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to scan a `DynamoDB` table, getting all of the items that are near a location:

```
func getPosts(location: CLLocation, radius: Int, limit: Int){
    let rad = Double(Double(radius) * 0.01)
    let latMin = location.coordinate.latitude - rad
    let latMax = location.coordinate.latitude + rad
    let lonMin = location.coordinate.longitude - rad
    let lonMax = location.coordinate.longitude + rad

    var latMinA: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    latMinA.N = "\(latMin)"
    var latMaxA: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    latMaxA.N = "\(latMax)"
    var lonMinA: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    lonMinA.N = "\(lonMin)"
    var lonMaxA: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    lonMaxA.N = "\(lonMax)"

    var vals: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [":latMin" : latMinA, ":latMax" : latMaxA, ":lonMin" : lonMinA, ":lonMax" : lonMaxA]

    var filter = "(Latitude BETWEEN :latMin AND :latMax) and (Longitude BETWEEN :lonMin AND :lonMax)"

    self.scan("Posts", select: AWSDynamoDBSelect.AllAttributes, attributes: nil, filterAttributes: vals, startKeyName: nil, startKey: nil, limit: nil, filter: filter)
}

func scan(table: String, select: AWSDynamoDBSelect, attributes: [String]?, filterAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, startKeyName: String?, startKey: String?, limit: Int?, filter: String?){
     let dynamo: AWSDynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB.defaultDynamoDB()

     var fa: String = ""
     if(attributes != nil){
         for attribute in attributes!{
             fa+=(fa == "" ? "" : ", ")
             fa+=attribute
         }
     }

     var val: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
     val.S = startKey

     let input: AWSDynamoDBScanInput = AWSDynamoDBScanInput()
     input.tableName = table
     input.exclusiveStartKey = startKeyName != nil && startKey != nil ? [startKeyName! : val] : nil
     input.limit = limit == nil ? nil : NSNumber(unsignedInteger: limit!)
     input.filterExpression = filter
     input.expressionAttributeNames = filterAttributes
     input.select = select
     input.projectionExpression = fa == "" ? nil : fa


     dynamo.scan(input).continueWithBlock({(task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
         if(task.error != nil){println("An error occurred while scanning in DynamoDB table \(table). Message: '\(task.error)'")}

         return nil
     })
 }
```

`latMin`, `latMax`, `lonMin`, and `lonMax` are calculated correctly, and everything works, except for when I attempt to scan the table. When scanning the table, I get this error:

```json
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSJSONBuilderErrorDomain Code=4 "serialized object is not a valid json Object: {
  ExpressionAttributeNames =     {
    ":latMax" = "<AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue: 0x7fe1c3e6f6d0> {\n    N = \"33.820303\";\n}";
    ":latMin" = "<AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue: 0x7fe1c3ea33d0> {\n    N = \"33.740303\";\n}";
    ":lonMax" = "<AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue: 0x7fe1c3ea0cf0> {\n    N = \"-118.378292\";\n}";
    ":lonMin" = "<AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue: 0x7fe1c3e7cf90> {\n    N = \"-118.458292\";\n}";
  };
  FilterExpression = "(Latitude BETWEEN :latMin AND :latMax) and (Longitude BETWEEN :lonMin AND :lonMax)";
  Select = "ALL_ATTRIBUTES";
  TableName = Posts;
}
```

`Latitude` and `Longitude` are `Number` data types, and are also `Local Secondary Indexes`. I don't parse any JSON, it's all done by AWS.

I've tried setting the filter to:

```
var filter = "(Latitude BETWEEN \(latMin) AND \(latMax)) and (Longitude BETWEEN \(lonMin) AND \(lonMax))"
```

and also just setting it to:

```
var filter = "(Latitude BETWEEN 100 AND 200) and (Longitude BETWEEN 100 AND 200)"
```

But I still get the same error. The same thing occurs when I try setting the filter and the attributeValues to:

```
var lat: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
lat.S = "Latitude"
var lon: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
lon.S = "Longitude"

var vals: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [":lat" : lat, ":lon" : lon]

var filter = "(:lat BETWEEN \(latMin) AND \(latMax)) and (:lon BETWEEN \(lonMin) AND \(lonMax))"
```

But I still get this:

```json
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSJSONBuilderErrorDomain Code=4 "serialized object is not a valid json Object: {
  ExpressionAttributeNames =     {
    ":lat" = "<AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue: 0x7fd69afa77b0> {\n    S = Latitude;\n}";
    ":lon" = "<AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue: 0x7fd69afe2fc0> {\n    S = Longitude;\n}";
  };
  FilterExpression = "(:lat BETWEEN 33.740303 AND 33.820303) and (:lon BETWEEN -118.458292 AND -118.378292)";
  Select = "ALL_ATTRIBUTES";
  TableName = Posts;
}
```

Should I just filter the results myself, without using the filter that is [included in the AWS API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)?

Answer (score -1):

`expressionAttributeNames` of `AWSDynamoDBScanInput` needs to be a `String` : `String` dictionary. See [AWSDynamoDBScanInput Class Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBScanInput.html#//api/name/expressionAttributeNames) for further details.

Also, if you are using a framework instead of CocoaPods, make sure to update `dynamodb-2012-08-10.json` to the latest version.

Comment: It looks like the value actually has to be a `AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue`. I just tried with `[String : String]` and I got a syntax error, `ExpressionAttributeNames contains invalid key: Syntax error`, in the console.

Comment: No, it needs to be a `String` : `String` dictionary. Take a look at the [service definition](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/DynamoDB/Resources/dynamodb-2012-08-10.json#L859) of Amazon DynamoDB. The key and value are both mapped to the `string` data type. If you get a syntax error, it means you may have another error in your code. You should post the updated code snippet with the error message.